# function derivative at $0$ for $f(a+b)=f(a)f(b)$

Tags: calculus

Let $\ f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}\ $ ,has derivative at $0$ and the function is not equal identity to $0$.

In addition for  $\forall a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ we have $f(a+b)=f(a)f(b)$

Prove the following claims:

$\quad  1)f$ has detrative in all $\mathbb{R}$

$\quad  2)f(x)=e^{\left( (xf'(0) \right)}$

I was able to prove the section $1$, so you can assume it is true.
I was stuck trying to solve the section $2$.

Thank you

Comment: Did you mean derivative?

Answer (score 1):

Hints: If $f(a)=0$ then $f(b)=f(a)f(b-a)=0$ for all $b$. Hence $f(a) \neq 0$ for all $a$. Being continuous $f$ is always positive or always negative. From the given equation conclude that it is always positive. Let $g(x)=\ln (f(x))$. Then $g(a+b)=g(a)+g(b)$ for all $a,b$. From this show that $g(na)=ng(a)$. Replacing $a$ by $\frac  a m$ show that $g(ra)=rg(a)$ for all $r \in \mathbb Q$. Using continuity show that $g(ra)=rg(a)$ for all $r, a \in \mathbb R$, Put $r=\frac  1 a$. I will leave the rest to you.

Comment: Thank you (: !!.

Answer (score 0):

Let  $f:R→R$ has derivative at 0 but the function is non-zero

We have $f(a+b)=f(a)f(b) ;∀a,b∈R$

Now it is easy to prove that(Using Functional Equations),

$ f(x)=e^{cx}$ or  $a^{x}$ ;Here $ a=e^{c} $

Now,$ f'(x)=a^{x}ln(a)$

So,$f'(0)=ln(a)$

Comment: Thank you (: !!.